# Finding on which element a particular keyboard listener is waiting on

Tags: jquery, keyboard-events

In a website which I visit everyday, when I press the key `b`, it opens a form. I have been trying to open the form using jQuery, but I don't seem to get it working.

Since the below code is not opening up the form, can I conclude they did not add the event listener on any of the DOM elements?

Appreciate any help figuring out on which element the listener is on..

```js
$("*").each(function() {

  $(this).trigger(
    jQuery.Event('keydown', {
      keyCode: "98",
      which: "98"
    })

  )

  $(this).trigger(
    jQuery.Event('keyup', {
      keyCode: "98",
      which: "98"
    })
  )


  $(this).trigger(
    jQuery.Event('keypress', {
      keyCode: "98",
      which: "98"
    })
  )
})
```

Comment: If the form opens after pressing `b` anywhere on the page it's most likely an event attached to the `document`. Also note that you can see the event handlers attached to any element in the DOM through dev tools

Comment: Oh right! I'll give it a try and get back quick. Ty

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just checked `document` and `window` using `$(document).trigger(...)` and `$(window).trigger(...)`. Didn't work :(

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am now looking at the event listeners in chrome developer tools. Looks very interesting.. I'll get back soon. Ty so much!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I see `keydown` event on "body" itself: https://prnt.sc/nvxn3j

Comment: There you go :) If you click the link to the right it will show you the actual JS logic - although it may not be legible if it's been minified.

Comment: Yeah those js files are minified..a bit hard to traverse... but now I know what to do next Thanks to you :) You're awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this may not directly answer your question but it should definitely help!

If you add the "Visual Event" bookmarklet and use it to visualise the events.

http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event

[image]

You probably want to be looking for the `keydown` `keyup` `keypress` icons which will most likely be in the top left of the window.

[image]